# Regarding approaches to make a chatbot

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, chatbot

I am creating a chatbot.Chatbot contains features like it will play some jokes,  it will search on the internet regarding question like tell me about Tajmahal and when did Mahatma Gandhi was born,for that I am using wiki search API and web scraping.am also adding a conversation talk in that like  hi how are you, I am your friend or not like  normal conversation. But when I say I am your friend it will search to Wikipedia but I don't want that. So how do I train my chatbot when to search on Wikipedia and when to reply from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keywords, that's what I am using for my personal assistant.
The way I do it is that I created a list with several strings inside, so something like this:

```
Hello_Keywords = ["Hello", "Cheers", "How are you"]
Jokes_Keywords = ["Tell me a joke", "Can you tell me a joke", "Make me laugh"
```

Then what you would do is assign these lists to functions. So something like this:

```
def Hello():
    print("Hello there")

def Jokes():
    print("Why did the chicken cross the road?")
    time.sleep(3) 
    print("To get to the other side!")

if User in Hello_KeyWords
   Hello()
elif User in Jokes_Keywords
   Jokes()
else:
    print("Excuse me what?")
```

Now to answer your specific question about Wikipedia, you could do something along the lines of:

```
User = "What is Python"

if "what is" in User:
    User = User.split("is")
    User = User[1].strip()
    User = wikipedia.summary(User)
    print(User)
```

The above code would check if the User said `"what is"` and then split the variable into a list, `["What", "Python"]`, and then take the second part (User[1]) and look it up on Wikipedia and then afterwards, prints it. Obviously, you can do this with other Keywords too like `"who is"` or `"search Wikipedia for"`, etc

That's what I use, I hope it helps!